# Extract year/month from date python to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a column with dates in object type

`> df['created_at_first']`

Thats the result

```
created_at_first
2018-07-01 02:08:06
2018-06-05 01:39:30
2018-05-16 21:18:48
```

I would like to create new columns for year, month, day, hour.
So I get something like that:

```
year  month  day  hour 
2018   07    01   02
2018   06    05   01
2018   05    16   21
```

How can I manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas-series-dt-strftime) and then to split on `'-'` as given inside `strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H')` function. The code:

```
created_at_first=["2018-07-01 02:08:06","2018-06-05 01:39:30","2018-05-16 21:18:48"]
df=pd.DataFrame({'ColumnName':created_at_first})
df['ColumnName']= pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnName'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.ColumnName.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H').str.split('-').tolist(),
                   columns=['Year','Month','Day','Hour'],dtype=int)
df2
    Year Month Day Hour
0   2018    07  01   02
1   2018    06  05   01
2   2018    05  16   21
```

If you want all the columns in a single dataframe use `pd.concat()` along `axis=1`.

```
pd.concat((df,df2),axis=1)
    ColumnName          Year Month Day Hour
0   2018-07-01 02:08:06 2018    07  01   02
1   2018-06-05 01:39:30 2018    06  05   01
2   2018-05-16 21:18:48 2018    05  16   21
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this method as your split series will be of dtype `object`, generally inefficient in Pandas. You could convert back to `int`, but that raises the question why go from `datetime` -> `str` -> `int`?

Comment: @jpp I accept that it is not the best solution, but initially when I answered the other solutions were breaking down each element manually. So thought why not break them all at once (DateTime elements). Also, I forgot that `strftime` gives output as `object` datatype added `dtype=int`. I appreciate your time and knowledge to write the comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe:

```
df['created_at_first'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_first'])
df['year'] = df['created_at_first'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['created_at_first'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['created_at_first'].dt.day
df['hour'] = df['created_at_first'].dt.hour
```

Answer (score 2):

One flexible approach is to use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html). Such an approach enables you to specify an arbitrary list of properties, which are then extracted via the [`pd.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html) accessor.

```
fields = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']

res = pd.concat(attrgetter(*fields)(df['dates'].dt), axis=1, keys=fields)

print(res)

   year  month  day  hour
0  2018      7    1     2
1  2018      6    5     1
2  2018      5   16    21
```

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import attrgetter

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['2018-07-01 02:08:06',
                             '2018-06-05 01:39:30',
                             '2018-05-16 21:18:48']})

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`DatetimeIndex` will be helpful to get required result

```
created_at_first=["2018-07-01 02:08:06","2018-06-05 01:39:30","2018-05-16 21:18:48"]
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({'ColumnName':created_at_first})
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ColumnName']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ColumnName']).month
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ColumnName']).day
df['hour'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ColumnName']).hour
```

official Document: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

output:

```
            columnName  year  month  day  hour
0  2018-07-01 02:08:06  2018      7    1     2
1  2018-06-05 01:39:30  2018      6    5     1
2  2018-05-16 21:18:48  2018      5   16    21
```